# Creating .exe from Python files "lib not found"

Tags: python, pyqt

I get a lot of warnings when I try to create an executable from python files (please see the code below).

I found in many forums that it could be related to "Microsoft C++ 2015", so I reinstalled it but it doesn't work.
I tried a lot of solutions like uploading software that allows creating executables automatically, etc.

Do you have any ideas to suggest to me? 
PS: I'm using pyinstaller, pyqt5 and python36.

```
7078 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python.exe

7319 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python.exe

7543 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python.exe

7752 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python.exe

7966 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python.exe

8167 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll

8364 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll

8560 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll

8764 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll

8960 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll

9177 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

9372 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

9567 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

9773 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

9960 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

10162 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

10360 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

10552 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

10762 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

10987 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

11187 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll

11377 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36\python36.dll
```

Comment: Add `--hidden-import ctypes`  to `pyinstaller` command .

Comment: @Pedro I had tried to add --hidden-import ctypes but it does not work

Comment: Also try: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vz0AEi3VCY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You system lacks the [Visual C++ Redistributable Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and you'll need to install one of the packages bellow according to your system architecture in order to fix it.

---

## The latest supported Visual C++ downloads

### Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019

---

Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/). The following updates are the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable packages for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019. Included is a baseline version of the Universal C Runtime see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=vs-2019) for details.

- x86: [vc_redist.x86.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x86.exe)
- x64: [vc_redist.x64.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)

**Note** Visual C++ 2015, 2017 and 2019 all share the same redistributable files.

For example, installing the Visual C++ 2019 redistributable will affect programs built with Visual C++ 2015 and 2017 also. However, installing the Visual C++ 2015 redistributable will not replace the newer versions of the files installed by the Visual C++ 2017 and 2019 redistributables.

This is different from all previous Visual C++ versions, as they each had their own distinct runtime files, not shared with other versions.

### Visual Studio 2013 (VC++ 12.0)

---

- Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3179560). This is the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable package for Visual Studio 2013.
- Download [Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2013](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=1430). This add-on for Visual Studio 2013 contains the multibyte character set (MBCS) version of the Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) Library.
- Download [Visual C++ 2013 Runtime for Sideloaded Windows 8.1 apps](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/0/5f0f8404-9329-44a9-8176-ed6f7f746f25/vclibs_redist_packages.zip).

For more information, see [C++ Runtime for Sideloaded Windows 8.1 apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/08/01/c-runtime-for-sideloaded-windows-8-1-apps.aspx) on [the VC++ Team Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/).

### Visual Studio 2012 (VC++ 11.0)

---

Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=1452). This is the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable package for Visual Studio 2012.

### Visual Studio 2010 (VC++ 10.0) SP1

---

- Download the [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=963). This is the latest supported Visual C++ service pack for Visual Studio 2010.

  Note

  This web installer requires an internet connection. This installer downloads and installs Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1. It works for all editions of Visual Studio 2010 (Express, Professional, Premium, Ultimate, and Test Professional).
- Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=26999). This is the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable package update for Visual Studio 2010.

### Visual Studio 2008 (VC++ 9.0) SP1

---

- Visual Studio 2008 reached [end of support on April 10, 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search?alpha=Visual%20Studio%202008). To aid the discovery of the latest downloads, the links are retained currently, but may be removed in the future.
- Download the [Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=620). This is the latest Visual C++ service pack for Visual Studio 2008. This service pack improved responsiveness, stability, and performance.
  **Note** This download installs Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 and Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.
- Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=26368). This is the latest Visual C++ redistributable package update for Visual Studio 2008.

---

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: Oh it works perfectly, thank you so much.